Old posts should be archived to prevent useless edits
CodePlex's icon
This is a 9-year-old bug report. It was fixed. Meta is for bug reports; thus, it is not off-topic. I don't know who closed it and why; there might be another edit pending.
I don't want to get notifications about 8-10 years old posts that do not do anything useful. If closing the post was done by a user, it should be restricted. If it was automation and you're just cleaning up the old environment, then disable notifications and use real remove reason.

Closing a post is not an "edit", never mind the utility.

I'll ignore the history this meta post had. Upvote from me for "disabling notifications", seems like a good idea to not send out notifications when it's a generic cleanup of obsolete material. We don't need more noise. The entire archiving bit is fluff though, no need for any of that. If no notifications are sent out, all problems are solved.

Stack Overflow Jobs functionality was removed almost 3 years ago. Your bug report about that product is no longer useful because the whole Jobs functionality was discontinued.
We have used a real close reason i.e. that

The problem described here can no longer be reproduced. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete


The relevant portion of the close reason is "Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete," which is specifically for questions, including bug reports and feature requests, which are no longer valid/reasonable due to system changes, rather than the "can no longer be reproduced" sentence.

I have nothing to do with that fact jobs was removed 3 years ago. You sent me a notification about something I dont need to do anything on a question that no one views. I stand for my suggestion: archive the post and do not send useless notificstion to people. https://imgur.com/a/72kYIe2

That bug was fixed within a few days. Following your logic all fixed bugs could be deleted as being off-topic since they can no longer be reproducet, which is the goal of submitting bug reports...

@klenium by "archive", did you mean "lock as historical significant"? Because there's really no archiving feature on SE network.

@AndrewT. Well maybe develop one. Archiving an object means that there will be no update on it, so no notification too. An archived item does not require interaction from anyone, can be hidden - I'm sure no one would miss it. It could be sliently removed if the database storage is so needed.

@klenium feel free to propose it as a [meta-tag:feature-request], because only SE Staff can make a change to their software, all of us (including mods) are just the users...

@AndrewT. I posted this under the tag you linked. What else should I do?

@klenium How would you determine whether a notification is "useless" or not? There are plenty of old posts that are still relevant and people might want to be notified about those. In any case, this is an awful lot of fuss about an extremely minor inconvenience.

@JohnMontgomery read my post, already answered.

@klenium I don't see anything there except for you complaining that it's old, and old posts can sometimes still be useful.
